# Cordova 3.6.3 File plugin - get local video file on android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, video, cordova-plugins

What I'd like to do is

1. get the URI of a video file on the device via cordovas javascript API
2. set the URI as value of a HTML5 `video` tag's `src` attribute.

The second part shouldn’t be a problem.
Concerning the first task, there are a lot of good structured tutorials like [Raymond Camden's](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/blob/master/getfiledata/www/js/app.js) demonstrating how to get local files through javascript in an [cordova](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file) environment.

However, with the newest version of cordova, I could not get it to work.

### The video file

The video is located either in `assets/www/videos/testvid.webm` or `res/raw/testvid.webm` in the built apk file. Both variations did not work.

### The javascript

```
myPath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory; // -> file:///android_asset/
//myPath += "www/videos/testvid.webm";
```

respectively

```
myPath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory; // -> file:///data/data/com.example.MyPackage/
//myPath += "raw/testvid.webm";
```

Then:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(myPath, gotFile, fail);
function gotFile(entry){
  if(entry.isDirectory)
    alert JSON.stringify(entry.getFile("testvid.webm"));
}
```

### The permissions

In `res/xml/config.xml` access permissions are added

```
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
```

The error is {code:1} -> NOT_FOUND_ERR

What am I doing wrong? How to navigate to the file, or where can one put it to be found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out!

There is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7273) in the android version of the cordova file plugin.

A workaround is transferring the file(s) from the assets directory of the app itself `file:///android_asset/` (cordova.file.applicationDirectory) to a working directory on the phone like `file:///data/data/com.example.MyPackage/files` (cordova.file.dataDirectory). Then set the video's source URL to this new file.

[XMLHttpRequest](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/mQLdrDB5B6Y/AEoU6cG0SKEJ) as well as [FileTransfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300176/phonegap-build-download-image-in-one-of-the-folders-of-your-app) will do the trick.

```
var myFilename = "testvid.webm";
var myUrl = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/videos/" + myFilename;
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + myFilename;

fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(myUrl), filePath, (function(entry) {
  /*
  res = "download complete:\n"
  res += "fullPath: " + entry.fullPath + "\n"
  res += "localURL: " + entry.localURL + "\n"
  alert(res += "nativeURL: " + entry.nativeURL + "\n")
   */
  var vid = document.getElementById("someID");
  vid.src = entry.nativeURL;
  vid.loop = true;
}), (function(error) {
  alert("Video download error: source " + error.source);
  alert("Video download error: target " + error.target);
}), true, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
  }
});
```

Comment: This code saved me a lot of time chasing my own tail :) Thanks @mab

Comment: Thank you so much ! Lost a day on this before i saw your post.