# HTML5 Video on Android using Phonegap 3.4

Tags: android, html, video, cordova

For the life of me, I cannot get any video to play using the HTML5 video tag in the android webview using phonegap 3.4.  I realize that there are many questions regarding HTML5 video in the android webview, but most of the answers are old and refer to older versions of phonegap.

I've tried using the plugin here:

https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer

but I'm new to phonegap and I can't get the plugin working.  I'm not sure where to put the .java file or how to reference it in the project.

Can anyone who has gotten this plugin to work help me set up my project? (i.e. where does the .java file go and how do I reference it?)

Comment: Are you using the cordova command line client?

Comment: yea, can i simply use cordova plugin add  https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer?

Comment: oh that appears to have worked

Comment: how do I specify the `<video>` tag that the VideoPlayer object should target?

Comment: Instead of using a `<video>` tag you make a javascript call like this `VideoPlayer.play("http://path.to.my/video.mp4");`. Most people a displaying a thumbnail from the video and assigning the click action to to the plugin's `play` method.

Comment: I need way more control than that... my app is a single-page app that uses video within the interface itself.  The video can't take up the entire screen and must be able to play without the user interacting with the video control.  It has to be controllable via javascript entirely.

Comment: Sorry, sounds like this plugin won't work.

Comment: ok, if I modify your plugin to support injection into an HTML5 video tag, are you interested in having me post the changes to your github?

Comment: yes! That would be great. I'll submit it to phonegap build as a revision as well. Post issues on the repo if you need any help or have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have ditched all the video plugin stuff as it really was not helping me out at all. You can keep the video tag. Just try using this reference using your package name:

```
src="android.resource://com.oest.freshwater/raw/caddisfly"
```

Move the video files into a new directory called "raw" that sits inside the platforms->Android->res folder. You will notice on the link above, the extension of the file (.mp4) is omitted. It is very important NOT to add the extension in the source.

Don't bother trying to get it work in emulator, it will just crash most of the time. Make sure you include a reference to a poster image as the html video player will not display a thumbnail of the video at all.

I should definitely give credit to @Prasanta Barman in their stackoverflow post at [Loading video failed on html5 phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007788/loading-video-failed-on-html5-phonegap/20660189?noredirect=1#comment33991200_20660189) as this is where I got my solution from.